# Ant build dex no response

Tags: java, android, ant, dex

When I try to build my android project with ant, 
sometimes I will get fail without any response.

When the project build success, it takes 5 min.
When the project build fail, it may takes more than 60 min, 
no any response from command line window.

The output log will stop in here:

```
  [dex] input: D:\Activity\bin\proguard\obfuscated.jar
  [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\Activity\bin\classes.dex...
```

Anyone get the same problem like me?
How to fix it?

Thanks for your attention.